# hadoop Error: Could not find or load main class MultiOutWordCount

Tags: hadoop

When I run this command in terminal:

MacBook-Pro:bin brown1$ hadoop MultiOutWordCount inputFile.txt out9

This is What I get:

Error: Could not find or load main class MultiOutWordCount

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you want to do..?? Do you want to run  a jar named MultiOutWordCount

Answer (score 0):

If you want you run your program on hadoop, you should package it to a jar file. And then use hadoop "jar" command to run it.
Advise you to study the WordCount how to run.